# show hidden footer on scroll down on last slide

Tags: jquery, html, css

I use `peachananr/onepage-scroll` plugin, I need to show hidden footer on scroll down after last slide. Something like  [this](http://www.takeitapp.co/) (scroll to bottom and you will see).

My code can be found on [this URL](http://abdullayev.besaba.com/jet/)

Comment: Show us your code..what you have tried..

Comment: http://abdullayev.besaba.com/jet/

Comment: Added the code link from the comment in to the answer.

Comment: @TofikAbdullayev You did it right. What's the problem now?

Comment: @PraveenKumar When I reach last slide and scroll down, the animation breakes, and I have no idea why

Comment: and i spent 2 days to solving this problem,but i can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy.
Use [fullpage.js library](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) with the class `fp-auto-height` in the last section as detailed [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-sections).

[Demo online](http://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/qOWoZd)

```
<div class="section fp-auto-height">Auto height</div>
```

Then you can use other options to configure it as you want, add the navigation bullets, fire actions on section load...